# Error in code to indicate sum using 'while'

Tags: python

F(N) = sigma k from 0 to N (1 / n^3)

I codedᅵF(N + 1) - F(N)ᅵ < 10^(-4). But the code didn't work out what the problem was. I'll attach the code below, so please point out if you know what's wrong.

```
N = 1

x = 1 / (10 ** 4)

y = 0
z = 0

while True:
  y += (1 / (N ** 3))
  z += (1 / (N + 1) ** 3)
  if abs(z - y) < x:
     break
  N += 1
print("(a) N = {N}".format(N=N))
```

An error message has not occurred and is still running

Comment: `z` is growing faster than `y` here, so if `abs(z - y) < x` is not true initially, i'm thinking the absolute value only increases so `break` is never hit

Comment: Wolfram Alpha: [(1/(N+1)^3) - (1/N^3)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F(N%2B1)%5E3)+-+(1%2FN%5E3))

Answer (score 0):

I put a print statement inside the loop and it looks like the exit condition approaches 1, not zero, so the loop will never terminate. (I also put if N>20: break in at the end to exit the loop).

```
0.875
0.962962962962963
0.984375
0.992
0.9953703703703703
0.9970845481049562
0.998046875
0.9986282578875171
0.9989999999999999
0.9992486851990983
0.9994212962962961
0.9995448338643602
0.9996355685131193
0.9997037037037035
0.9997558593749998
0.9997964583757376
0.9998285322359393
0.9998542061525
0.9998749999999996
0.9998920203001831
```